# Spring boot: sFtp client inside spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've created a spring-boot service.

I need to connect to an sFTP server in order to download remote files from server and process them locally (on spring-boot service) and asynchronously.

I've been google over there, but I don't quite find how to solve that. I mean, which libraries should I use...

Any ideas?

Comment: I googled “java sftp library”: https://github.com/andreiruse/awesome-java-sftp/

Answer (score -2):

It's not a good practise to exchange files with remote server using java ( except for common protocols like HTTP ) .. You should call a wrapper shell script from Java application .. and you call the sftp/ftps command from the script

The main reason in to use system infrastrcutre ( with up to date security patches , SSL certificates , proxies configurations ) and make execution's platform complexity/changes transparent to your application

Comment: This doesn’t sound like good advice. It’s not cross platform and introduces unnecessary dependency on external binaries and a lot of inconvenience.

Comment: It is based on experience with sFTP and other file exchange protocol